# How to diff between current branch and base, instead of typing parent branch

Tags: git

Example)
there are a `develop` branch and `feature` branch, which is derived from `develop` branch, and i'm currently working on `feature` branch

I know that the common way to diff between current branch and base is

`git diff feature...develop`

But what if i just want to diff between `current branch` and `base`, not typing `develop` branch?

(I don't want to type develop branch.)

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current branch can be named in two ways:

- by its name, e.g., `develop` or `feature` or `master`, or
- by the name `HEAD`.

Hence if you are currently on `develop` and wish to do `git diff feature...develop` without typing out the seven letters `d`, `e`, `v`, `e`, `l`, `o`, `p`, you can run:

```
git diff feature...HEAD
```

This isn't really much improvement by itself, except that in a script, `HEAD` automatically refers to the current branch, whatever that is.  For fewer command-line keystrokes, though—assuming that's the goal—consider the fact that `@` by itself is an alias for `HEAD`, so that you can type in:

```
git diff feature...@
```

Last, *omitting* the name `HEAD` works in some cases.  This particular kind of `git diff` is one of these.  Hence you can type in:

```
git diff feature...
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at this point, without typing `@` or `HEAD` or `develop` at all.  (The set of Git commands and arguments that allow this is tricky.  Consult the Git documentation for each case, to find out if this works for other commands and/or arguments.)

In your case, you're currently on `feature`, so you need to reverse all of the above:

```
git diff ...develop
```

That is, you can leave out the name `feature`, because that's your *current* branch, but you can't leave out the name `develop`.  (Note: This kind of diff compares the merge-base of `feature` and `develop` to the tip of `develop`, and if you're currently on `feature`, this is not all that often the right diff to obtain, which is why I read the question the other way around at first.)

(Note: there's no such thing in Git as a *base branch*.  Git*Hub* have the concept of a *base branch*, but not Git.  The base branch is per-PR, in GitHub.  One might argue that Git *should* have this as a concept, but it doesn't.)